# DNS lookup for TXT records not resolving for some valid domains

Tags: node.js, dns

The following code pulls TXT records for denverpost.com

```
var dns = require('dns');
dns.resolve('denverpost.com', 'TXT', function(err, addresses) {
    console.log(err, addresses);
});
```

This works as expected.

```
null [ 'v=spf1 ip4:65.125.148.55 a:reviewlistrak.com include:sid.listrak.com inc
lude:listrak.com include:_spf.google.com include:amazonses.com include:spf.imsho
pping.net include:sendgrid.net ~all']
```

I have a domain hosted on godaddy with several TXT records, but when I perform the same lookup it fails with ENODATA.

```
var dns = require('dns');
dns.resolve('postralmail.com', 'TXT', function(err, addresses) {
    console.log(err, addresses);
});
```

returns

```
{ [Error: queryTxt ENODATA] code: 'ENODATA', errno: 'ENODATA', syscall: 'queryTxt' } undefined
```

Why would a DNS lookup fail with some domains but not others? Is this a registrar issue, a DNS issue, or a Node issue?

Comment: Nothing to do with node.js. Neither `nslookup` nor `dig` return any TXT records for postralmail.com either, but do for denverpost.com. I suggest moving to ServerFault.

Comment: The domain you're testing currently doesn't have any TXT (at least from 8.8.8.8). I tried `dig -t any postralmail.com` and it returned only A+NS+SOA+MX. Are you sure it has any TXT? Maybe you're using different DNS servers to query it and one of them didn't get the propagation yet?

Comment: I had to add TXT records to verify the domain with AWS SES, so I know they are there and visible to AWS at least. This was several days ago, so propagation should not be an issue.

Comment: I have another domain with godaddy that I know has a ton of cname records, but this similar query returns ENODATA as well: dns.resolve('postral.com', 'CNAME', function(err, addresses) {
    console.log(err, addresses);
});

Comment: @user548084: then the problem may be something else. It's fact that the domain no longer has those TXT entries. You can check yourself using https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/

Comment: @jweyrich While you are correct that this name does not have a TXT-record at the moment, it is not specified for a nameserver which records to return on a query for ANY. In fact, some nameservers implement to send the records which they have in their cache at the moment only and are perfectly compliant to RFC1035

Comment: @user548084 You probably verified this with the name `_amazonses.postralmail.com`, which indeed _has_ a TXT-record

Comment: @Ctx: my bad. Right, I did query by TXT as well, but didn't really know about that regarding ANY. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @Ctx - Where did you see the TXT record? I looked at the dig tool linked above and don't see it there? https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#TXT/postralmail.com. Also, when you say that the nameserver is not configured to return records on ANY, is that a GoDaddy issue? Would switching to cloudflare or something better help?

Comment: @user548084 `host -t TXT _amazonses.postralmail.com` => `_amazonses.postralmail.com descriptive text "UCZii2ILjUOgqBAJkFM56LayfHmaXrCAHIazX3QGr+4="`. No, asking for ANY is practically irrelevant, no need to change your DNS-provider because of this.